# ui router shows states on browser and not on device when run with cordova. How do I correct it?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

I'm just starting with angularjs so I'm not an expert with ui router as well. I'm developing an app using **cordova and ratchet**. So right now here's my code

### index.html

```
   <header class="bar bar-nav">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </header>

   <div ui-view></div>
```

### app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova','ui.router','myApp.controllers','myApp.services']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

$stateProvider

.state('tab',{
    url:'/tab',
    abstract:true,
    templateUrl:'/template/tab.html'
})

.state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/template/tab-home.html',
    controller:'HomeCtrl',
    controllerAs:'home'
})

.state('tab.history',{
    url: '/history',
    templateUrl:'template/tab-history.html'

})
.state('tab.sponsors',{
    url: '/sponsors',
    templateUrl:'template/tab-sponsors.html'

})
.state('tab.settings',{
    url: '/settings',

    templateUrl:'template/tab-settings.html'

})   
});
```

The Code seems to be working fine on the browser; but it does not show any views when I use **cordova run android**. Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i guess in your index.html you are calling in script files like below :-

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

..I also had the same issue(This was the problem that i faced).You need to ensure any external paths are absolute

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm calling the files locally.